# Symfony 2 sessions not persisting after created via AJAX call

Tags: php, ajax, session, symfony, symfony-2.1

Let me give you the scenario. I have an AJAX call that calls /auth - that page in turn checks if the user is authenticated and sets a couple session variables (code below).

```
$session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();

$session->set('fbid', $fbid);
$session->set('name', $name);

// not sure if this is even needed - get the same with or without
//$session->save();
```

Now if I go to another page and try to access that session, it comes back empty.

If I set those sessions on a regular page (not one accessed via XMLHttpRequest/AJAX), it works fine.

Here are my session settings in `config.yml`:

```
session:         
    cookie_lifetime:         3600
    cookie_httponly:         false
```

I thought that the problem may have been `httponly`, but that didn't do it.

Any suggestions? Am I missing something?

*** UPDATE ***

Here is my security/firewall settings:

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    login:
        pattern:  ^/demo/secured/login$
        security: false

    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/demo/secured/
        form_login:
            check_path: /demo/secured/login_check
            login_path: /demo/secured/login
        logout:
            path:   /demo/secured/logout
            target: /demo/
```

I haven't changed the firewall settings at all, and from what I can tell, it shouldn't be affecting the `/auth` call via XMLHttpRequest.

*** Update 2 ***

I ended up adding `$session->shutdown()` after the 2 sets (and yes I know that shutdown isn't a Session object method). It ended up getting an error, but because of that it started working and it actually saved it to $_SESSION. So, if that error forced it to save to $_SESSION, there has to be an actual method that forces the save. Really odd..

Comment: Do your AJAX routes match security firewall pattern?

Comment: I just added my Firewall settings to the question, and from what I can tell, it doesn't match it.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the Symfony 2 not actually writing the session data to $_SESSION for some reason. Is there any way to force it to write?

Comment: Ah, sorry for confusion. It has nothing to do with security.

Comment: Have you checked these links? [First](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9703186/970721) and [second](http://garethmccumskey.blogspot.com/2009/10/php-session-write-locking-and-how-to.html)

Comment: Yeah, they are referring to Symfony 1.* and the shutdown method was used on the user object, which doesn't manage the Session anymore. There has to be a way to force a write.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17075/discussion-between-thecatontheflat-and-xil3)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was.

The first session was being created on the production environment (the action called via AJAX / XMLHttpRequest), and the next page that I was testing it on was actually on the development environment. At the time, it never crossed my mind that Symfony 2 was actually saving the sessions for prod and dev in different spots - PHP usually has a default location where it saves them all.

Symfony 2 overwrites the default `session.save_path` and puts it's own for each - wasted a day before I found this out, unfortunately.

Also wrote an article on it, so others don't have to go through the same problem.

http://jondev.net/articles/Reasons_why_Symfony_2_sessions_might_not_always_persist

Comment: Thank you! I've been bashing my head trying to figure it out.

Comment: Where is the article?

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20160630020209/http://jondev.net/articles/Reasons_why_Symfony_2_sessions_might_not_always_persist