# Randomly very long cross domain ajax request with Symfony2

Tags: javascript, ajax, symfony

I have two subdomains client.domain.com and server.domain.com
The client is just a index.html with a simple jquery ajax POST request.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://server.domain.com/upload',
  type: 'POST',
  success: function(response){
    console.log(response);
  }
});
```

The server runs symfony2 and has Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers set to '*'.

The preflight OPTIONS request sent by the client is generally (80% of the time) very fast (100ms) and randomly very very long (10 to 15s [timeline](http://drp.io/byM) + [headers](http://drp.io/byN)).

I tested to send OPTIONS requests with Postman and there is absolutely no problem, always fast, so it seems to come from the jquery ajax request. Also symfony2 web profiler says that nothing is wrong with the slow request, so it seems not to come from the server.

I really dont know how to debug this, any suggestions ?

Comment: I don't know if this will help. But I find this article to be very informative on the issue: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: As a first step, try figuring out which part of the request lifecycle is being slow. You can use your browser’s developer tools (Chrome’s Timeline on the Network tab) and/or a network sniffer.

Comment: Develeper tools does not say much except the time the request take :( http://drp.io/byM

Comment: Do you have access to Symfony's profiler? You can search for your problematic request and view the timeline. Should provide some clues.

Comment: @phpisuber01 I used the web profiler to check the slow request and it seems not to come from symfony since the profiler says the request went fine and was fast :(

Comment: Sounds like a network issue then. Either on your side or the server.

Comment: @phpisuber01 The client and the server are on my localhost.... :(
127.0.0.1:9000 and a virtual host on 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

this seems to be a session locking problem. basically symfony blocks parallel requests with session.
try to add this code into your controller action, preferrably as soon as possible, but ofc not before you are done editing anything what could updated the session (usually user related):

```
public function uploadAction() {
    // code potentially affecting session

    session_write_close(); // unlock session to allow multiple requests with this session

    // rest of the code
}
```

more info:

- [send two ajax request at the same time in symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699284/send-two-ajax-request-at-the-same-time-in-symfony)
- http://blog.alterphp.com/2012/08/how-to-deal-with-asynchronous-request.html